# laravel 5.4 login using ajax. Authentication succeeded but redirectTo property not working and keep redirect to '/home'

Tags: ajax, laravel, authentication

I'm trying to create custom login using ajax in laravel, so the form validation error will be show faster in my opinion. I already suuceeded to shows form validation errors, shows message when credentials is false, and reload the login page when credentials is true. My problem is when the login page reloaded, it is still redirect the page to '/home' page, however i already set the redirectTo property to '/'.

this is my login controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Login Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
| redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
| to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
|
*/

use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
public function showLoginForm(){
  return view('auth.loginjax');
}
public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
public function login(Request $request){
  if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
    $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

    return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
  }
  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
    $this->username() => 'required|string',
    'password' => 'required|string',
  ]);
  $data = array();
  if ($validator->passes()) {
    $data['valid']=true;
    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
      // return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
      $data['masuk'] = true;
    }else {
      $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
      // return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
      $data['masuk'] = false;
    }
  }else {
    $data['namafield']=array();
    $data['texterror']=array();
    $data['valid']=false;
    if ($validator->errors()->has($this->username())) {
      $data['namafield'][]=$this->username();
      $data['texterror'][]=$validator->errors()->first($this->username());
    }
    if ($validator->errors()->has('password')) {
      $data['namafield'][]='password';
      $data['texterror'][]=$validator->errors()->first('password');
    }
  }
  return response()->json($data);
 }
}
```

my login controller is working fine(redirect to '/' page) when i login without ajax and without overriding the login method.

this is my ajax method

```
function masuk(){
  loadingSuccess("#alert_login");
  $('#btnMasuk').val('Konfirmasi..');
  $("#btnMasuk").attr("disabled",true);
  $.ajax({
    url:"{{ route('masuk') }}",
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#formLogin').serialize(),
    dataType:"JSON",
    success:function(data){
      $("#alert_login").html('');
      $("button").attr("disabled",false);
      if (data.valid) {
        if (data.masuk===true) {
          location.reload()
        }else {
          var div = "#alert_login";
          var message = "Kombinasi Nama Pengguna dan Kata Sandi Tidak Ditemukan";
          $('#username').focus();
          alertDanger(div,message);
        }
      }else{
        for (var i = data.namafield.length; i >= 0; i--)
        {
          $('[name="'+data.namafield[i]+'"]').focus();
          $('[name="'+data.namafield[i]+'"]').parent().addClass('has-error'); //select parent twice to select div form-group class and add has-error class
          $('[name="'+data.namafield[i]+'"]').next().text(data.texterror[i]);
        }
      }
      $('#btnMasuk').val('Masuk');
      $("#btnMasuk").attr("disabled",false);
    },
    error: function (data)
    {
      alert(data);
    }
  })
}
```

as you can see, i use location.reload() to reload the page.

please tell me if you know something and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work because the the LoginController simply returns the html of the page that you should be redirected after login, if you see the result in success closure of ajax you will see html. SO basically what you will have to do is when the ajax request is successful i.e the  `httpStatusCode == 200` then you will have to manually redirect the user to the page you want to with help of JS.

`window.href = '/home';`

Comment: yes, i think i'll do just like what you suggest. thanks!